# Get user timezone and geography in javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone

I am trying to get a user's timezone. I can do this, but how can I identify two geographic zones with same timezone, for example Arizona timezone is UTC-07:00 same that Mountain time (US & Canada) and when I get timezone from user I only get -07:00, but I don´t know if user is in Arizona timezone or Mountain time timezone. Any hint about how to identify this?

I need something like this code in Java:

```
TimeZone tz = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
System.out.println("TimeZone: "+tz.getDisplayName());
System.out.println("ID: "+tz.getID());
```

but for javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: I think I found a [simpler answer](http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2007/08/getting_the_time_zone_from_a_web_browser.html) to your problem. Look at the code at the bottom of this post.

<strike>Well, Arizona's time zone is the same as Mountain time zone. Therefore if someone is in Arizona time zone, they are also in Mountain time zone, and vice-versa. The two timezones are one and the same.</strike>

If you are just looking for your user's geographical location however, try using [this relevant api](http://www.geoplugin.net) in conjunction with some [code that looks like this](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/get-geographical-location-geolocation.html).

Basically what is done in this code is:

1. Your user's machine accesses geoplugin.net, which then returns info relating to the user's IP address.
2. You parse the returned data and do whatever you want with it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can obtain time zone, but for example UTC-07:00 belongs to America/Phoenix, America/Chihuahua and America/Denver. I want to identify which of this three locations is where user is.

Comment: If the function you're using to obtain this time zone just returns the time zone, then I'm afraid you can't determine which of these three geographical zones your user is in. However, by using the api linked above, you can cross-reference the location you get from the api with their timezone to figure out which section they're in. It will take some work, but that seems like the way to do it.

Comment: Just a statement for Jebego. Arizona timezone is not the same as Mountain TimeZone. Right now, the state of Arizona is on Pacific time. Come November, Arizona shifts back to Mountain Timezone. Arizona does not recognize daylight savings.

Comment: Oh wow! My bad, I forgot about how some regions don't recognize daylight savings time. Anyways, I looked around a bit more and found [this post](http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2007/08/getting_the_time_zone_from_a_web_browser.html) which answers your original question. I'll edit my original post to include this link.

Comment: As a tip: this is the most comprehensive javascript timezone detection script I have yet to find: Demo: http://site.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript. Code: https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/